# Estratégia para grandes queries

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, react, query, sequelize-js

estou trabalhando numa aplicação que apresenta um mapa e precisa renderizar centenas de milhares de markers. Os dados para renderização ficam no banco de dados e a consulta é onerosa.

Há também o desafio de renderizar todos esses markers no mapa sem prejudicar a velocidade da aplicação, o que tem sido um problema.

Uma das implementações que fiz foi uma renderização condicional de acordo com a parte do mapa que está sendo visualizada pelo cliente, desta forma, a aplicação vai renderizando tudo aos pouquinhos (ainda tem o problema de no caso do usuário dar um zoom-out muito rapidamente, o que será tratado).

Resumindo: todos os markers precisam ser renderizados (filtrar não é uma opção). Estou pensando em trazer esses dados aos poucos, uma espécie de paginação mas ainda não está claro pra mim o intervalo e o trigger que vai disparar uma nova requisição para buscar mais dados (não é como uma paginação convencional onde o cliente vai navegando por páginas de informações e uma próxima requisição fica atrelada a uma ação de click por exemplo).

Existe alguma estratégia mais assertiva para esses casos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma ideia para você: 
Como não tem código, imagens e outras coisas para descrever melhor não vou poder te ajudar muito. 
Mas uma ideia interessante é renderizar os markers por nivel, igual a renderização do google maps.

por exemplo, se voce está com um zoom-in alto, são carregadas todas as ruas da tela, mas se você der um zoom-out maior o mapa **não carrega todas as ruas daquela area**, mas apenas dados como relevantes que vão ser vistos como quadras, bairros ou cidade dependendo do tamanho do zoom.

Embora existam milhares de restaurantes naquela area apenas 1 foi renderizado
[image: Embora existam milhares de restaurantes naquela area apenas 1 foi renderizado]

Mas a medida que você dá zoom ele renderiza mais pontos

[image: Mas a medida que você dá zoom ele renderiza mais pontos]

Como voce que quer renderizar centenas de milhares de markers,
como visualizar todos eles de uma vez não seria muito viavel, dependendo do zoom voce pode mostrar um marker em alguns locais com o numero de locais naquela região. e a medida que der zoom-in você puxa do banco de dados mais markers apenas de certo quadrante(aonde está a visão do espectador).

Embora a ideia pareça simples, aplicar ela pode ser bem complexo mesmo com um alto nivel de conhecimento.

mas eu espero ter te ajudado a pelo menos te dar uma luz.